# Issue with for loop, taking in and utilising input

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to create a program that takes in item codes and checks if they are valid in a "Stock.txt" file that's formatted as follows:

```
ItemCode,ItemName,Quantity,Price
```

which has the contents:

```
jmpr,Jumper,30,13.99
tsrt,T-Shirt,12,4.99
shs,Shoes,9,14.99
trsrs,Trousers,3,9.99
jkt,Jacket,0,19.99
scks,Socks,11,3.99
muwear,Male Underwear,4,4.99
fuwear,Female Underwear,8,6.99
hat,Hat,0,7.99
txdo,Tuxedo,3,99.99
```

I ask for 1 or more item codes separated by a space and then the quantities in which they wish to buy also separated by a space, I then store the contents of the Stock.txt file into an ArrayList and scan through it to check if the item Code is present and if the corresponding quantity to that Item Code is less than or equal to that inside of the Stock.txt file, if it is then, it will be added to a String shoppingCart which I will be using later on. If the quantity is greater than the current stock amount, also if the Item Code is wrong I exit the program.

The issue I have is when I run the program, it asks for the Item Codes, then the Quantities and it goes down to the print statements at the end of the program, but when 1 is entered it asks for the Item Codes and Quantities again and not printing out "Purchasing..", I don't know what's wrong its not within the loop, any help would make my day.

*Sorry if there may be little errors in the code as I took it out and put it in its own class as I'm using it as a method in my other files.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Items
{
    public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static File stockFile    = new File("Stock.txt");
    public static void main() throws IOException
    {
        boolean valid = true;
        String shoppingCart = "";
        List<String[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner searchStockFile = new Scanner(stockFile);
        while(searchStockFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] current = searchStockFile.nextLine().split(",");
            contents.add(current);
        }
        System.out.println("\n----------Add Items----------");
        System.out.print("Enter Item Codes: ");
        String itemCodes = userInput.nextLine();
        String itemCodesArray[] = itemCodes.split(" ");

        System.out.print("Enter Item Quantities: ");
        String quantities = userInput.nextLine();
        String quantityArray[] = quantities.split(" ");
        int[] quantityIntArray = new int[quantityArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < quantityArray.length; i++)
            quantityIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityArray[i]);

        for(int i = 0; i < itemCodesArray.length; i++)
        {
            for(String[] elements : contents)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(itemCodesArray[i].equals(elements[0]) && Integer.parseInt(elements[2]) >= quantityIntArray[i])
                        shoppingCart += itemCodesArray[i] + "," + elements[1] + "," + elements[2] + "," + quantityIntArray[i] + "," + elements[3] + ".";

                    else if(itemCodesArray[i].equals(elements[0]) && Integer.parseInt(elements[2]) < quantityIntArray[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("The quantity of Item Code - " + itemCodesArray[i] + " - exceeds the current stock.");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("The Item code you entered does not exist.");
                    valid = false;
                }
                if(!valid)
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n----------Purchase/Hire Items----------");
        System.out.print("1. Purchase Item\n2. Quit\nEnter Option Number: ");
        String PH = userInput.nextLine();
        if(PH.equals("1"))
            System.out.println("Purchasing..)";
        else if(PH.equals("2"))
            System.out.println("Quitting..)";
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid Option chosen.\nPlease choose Options 1 or 2.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does adding an extra userInput.nextLine() before the second userInput.nextLine() help? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Do you mean on this line? "String quantities = userInput.nextLine();
"

Comment: Just before taking in the item quantities. userInput.nextLine();  System.out.print("Enter Item Quantities: "); String quantities = userInput.nextLine();

Comment: I left it out and now it gets down to the "---Purchase/Hire Items---" Options at the bottom of the code, but when I enter 1, Purchasing... is not output.

Comment: I edited my post, I made a mistake describing the issue, It does go down to "---Purchase/Hire Items---" but when selecting Option 1, it does not work.

Comment: Between every two calls to nextLine() try adding an extra call to nextLine() because it needs to eat the previous '\n'.

Comment: I tried it and it still does not print out "Purchasing..", would making PH an int and change it to userInput.nextInt();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop it back after user input if purchase, check this

```
 boolean valid = true;
    String shoppingCart = "";
    List<String[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner searchStockFile = new Scanner(stockFile);
    while (searchStockFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] current = searchStockFile.nextLine().split(",");
        contents.add(current);
    }
    String PH = "1";
    do {
        System.out.println("\n----------Add Items----------");
        System.out.print("Enter Item Codes: ");
        String itemCodes = userInput.nextLine();
        String itemCodesArray[] = itemCodes.split(" ");

        System.out.print("Enter Item Quantities: ");
        String quantities = userInput.nextLine();
        String quantityArray[] = quantities.split(" ");
        int[] quantityIntArray = new int[quantityArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < quantityArray.length; i++) {
            quantityIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(quantityArray[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCodesArray.length; i++) {
            for (String[] elements : contents) {
                try {
                    if (itemCodesArray[i].equals(elements[0]) && Integer.parseInt(elements[2]) >= quantityIntArray[i]) {
                        shoppingCart += itemCodesArray[i] + "," + elements[1] + "," + elements[2] + "," + quantityIntArray[i] + "," + elements[3] + ".";
                    } else if (itemCodesArray[i].equals(elements[0]) && Integer.parseInt(elements[2]) < quantityIntArray[i]) {
                        System.out.println("The quantity of Item Code - " + itemCodesArray[i] + " - exceeds the current stock.");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("The Item code you entered does not exist.");
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (!valid) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\n----------Purchase/Hire Items----------");
            System.out.print("1. Purchase Item\n2. Quit\nEnter Option Number: ");
            PH = userInput.nextLine();
            if (PH.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Purchasing..");
                break;
            } else if (PH.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Quitting..");
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Option chosen.\nPlease choose Options 1 or 2.");
            }
        }
    } while (PH.equals("1"));
```

Comment: Thank you, it's able to get down to there now, but when I try to change the  "Purchasing" code to a method call in my Checkout class, it will not call that method. This is my code inside my Item class now which should link to Checkout. Item Code: http://pastebin.com/69k89NpY Checkout Code: http://pastebin.com/N5tB3hCj